# How to find a set of examples for which an example is in the kNN set?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

I have the following problem: for each example $x^*$ I need to find all examples for which $x^*$ is in their k-nearest neighbourhood.
$$Is\_neighbour\_of(x^*)=\{x: x^* \in kNN(x) \}$$
There is a lot of techniques, like kd-trees, to perform k-nearest neighbours search quickly, but my problem is a reverse version of that problem. I want to find examples for which an example is in the k-nearest neighbour. Any algorithms besides brute force?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=higher-order+voronoi+diagram links to useful papers and books, such as Gavrilova (*ed*), *Generalized Voronoi Diagram[s]...*

Comment: "I want to find examples for which an example is in the k-nearest neighbour" << how is that the "reverse" of kNN?

Comment: @Redress To appreciate the distinction, consider $7$ points distributed at the center of a circle and uniformly around it (as a regular hexagon).  Perturb all their positions randomly a tiny bit so that they all have uniquely determined neighborhoods of three nearest points ("3-NNs"). The center is one of the three nearest neighbors of *every* point on the circle, but the set of the six points on the circle obviously does not constitute the 3-NN of the center.

Answer (score 2):

This is know as the reverse k nearest neighbors problem. There are a lot of algorithms. The most recent ones include InfZone, SLICE, FINCH, and SIX. Take a look at [*Reverse k nearest neighbors query processing: experiments and analysis*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2735492) by Yang et al for a detailed comparison. If your looking for actual implementations, there's one on Github in Java [here](https://github.com/wycarol44/RNN-KNN).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem boils down to finding a set of nearest points to a specific point.

The way I would solve this problem is by consuming a distance matrix, such as the one given by the methods in the `sklearn.metrics.pairwise` module, if you are using python.

If the data is too large, I would move towards more custom algorithms.

Comment: I believe "consuming a distance matrix" is precisely what the OP means by "brute force" :-).